# How do i update values in an SQL database? SQLite/Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have created a table, and have inserted data into the table. I wanted to know how I could update/edit the data. For example, if I have multiple columns in the table, of which one is named 'age' and the data for the column is = '17', and I now wanted to replace '17' with '18', would I do the following?

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('Records.db')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO ExampleTable(Age) VALUES(18) WHERE (Age = 17)")
```

Comment: You do an UPDATE query, which should be covered by whatever tutorial you're using to learn SQL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To update values in a SQL database using the SQLite library in Python, use a statement like this one.

`cur.execute("UPDATE ExampleTable SET Age = 18 WHERE Age = 17")`

For a great introduction to using SQLite in Python, see [this tutorial](http://www.pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-sqlite-in-python/).

Answer (score 18):

In sqlite3 with Python3.x works to me something like this:

```
newPrice = '$19.99'
book_id = 4
cursor.execute('''UPDATE books SET price = ? WHERE id = ?''', (newPrice, book_id))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not into Python, but i think i can help, so

```
cur.execute("UPDATE ExampleTable SET age = 18 WHERE age = 17")
```

If i'm wrong, sorry then

Answer (score 1):

```
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE Table_Name SET Age='18' WHERE Age='17'")
```

Answer (score -1):

you must use *update* operation Instead of *insert* operation to change records.

the  program would be as follows

```
cur=con.cursor()
com="update ExampleTable set age=1 where age=17"

try:
    cur.execute(com)

    con.commit()

except:

    print('error')
    con.rollback()

con.close()
```